# Manual Plugin Registration - Managed Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have some questions regarding the registering/updating of 3rd party plugins that were previously loaded via a managed solution by a 3rd party.

The issue we are having is that they(3rd party) sent us a plugin update and a new plugin outside of the Managed Solution and had us register it manually though the registration tool.  Then, next time we tried to import a later version of their solution, the Managed solution import failed.  We eventually realized that there where duplicate rows in the pluginassembly and pluginassemblytype table that had the same Pluginassemblyid and plugintypeid respectively with different solutionids.

These solutionids were "Active" which I assume came from the manual registration and "IPM Global" which is our 3rd Party Managed Solution.  The only way we were successful in getting the solution to import was to change the overwrite time 
on the table(s) to 0 and then delete the "Active" pluginassembly and plugintype records.

Is there any other way to accomplish this same thing that is supported?

BTW. We did try to unregister the plugins before trying this, but there were too many dependencies in our workflows.

Comment: Next time, request your vendor give you a managed solution with the updated plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to avoid direct DB updates in system tables whenever possible. You never know when it will hit you (next solution import, next CRM upgrade, moving to cloud, etc).

I assume that yours vendor solution contains entities and attributes and not only assemblies with SDK message processing steps. Thus you can't just simply remove that managed solution cause there will be data loss. Also I assume there are no workflow activities in their assemblies.

Ask them for solution with properly registered assemblies and SDK message processing steps. Then go into your organization with plugin registration tool (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309580.aspx) and unregister their assemblies. Then just import their latest solution. It should be able to import their assemblies with whatever is inside them.

It's good idea to restore copy of prod organization and playthrough whole process in safe environment first.

Comment: Good advice.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is a thorny problem. Since you mention updating the tables directly, I'll assume that the system is on-prem.

Registering a plugin that exists in a managed solution outside of that managed solution is something I've never done, and while I have directly updated the plugin registration table, it is certainly something to minimize.

As unpleasant as it sounds, to get back to a good state in a supported way you may be looking at having to:

*Backup the SQL database*

*Backup all the data from any managed solution entities.*

*Undo all dependencies on the managed solution (i.e. edit all the workflows so they no longer depend on the managed solution). To ease the pain of this piece you might want to experiment with exporting the affected workflows via an unmanaged solution. Then you could delete them rather than trying to weed out the dependencies. Then after you have the managed solution back in the system, you could theoretically import the unmanaged workflow solution to restore the workflow. But, admittedly this working depends on workflows finding the plugin assemblies they depend on by name rather than Id, which I'm not sure is the case - so like I said, experiment.*

*Unregister the "out-of-band" plugin*

*Uninstall the managed solution*

*Install a clean copy of the managed solution, INCLUDING the previously problematic plugin.*

*Restore/reconfigure the workflows*

*Restore the managed entities data*

It's a lot... so much in fact that I would consider opening a Microsoft support ticket to see if they can provide any alternative methods to correct the situation.

In this situation I personally might also consider unsupported methods like using SQL to copy the tables of any managed entities before deleting the managed solution and then using SQL to copy the data back after the managed solution is fixed. Of course I (almost) never recommend using SQL in an unsupported way, so explore that option at your own risk (and with copious backups).